# How to intercept paintComponent from Custom JButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, paintcomponent

I created a Custom JButton with transparent background and a drawn line from graphics.drawRoundRect() but when I start my program for testing, my JCheckbox keeps appearing on top of the button.

It looks like this at the beginning

[image]

And this is after I hover over the Button with the mousecursor

[image]

Here is the Code from the ***paintComponent*** Method

```
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.setColor(this.getForeground());
    graphics.drawRoundRect(2, 2, this.getWidth() - 4, this.getHeight() - 4, 30, 30);
    graphics.setFont(this.getFont());

    int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
    int centerY = getHeight() / 2;

    FontMetrics fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();
    Rectangle stringBounds = fontMetrics.getStringBounds(this.getText(), graphics).getBounds();

    int textX = centerX - stringBounds.width / 2;
    int textY = centerY + fontMetrics.getAscent() / 2;

    graphics.setColor(this.getForeground());
    graphics.drawString(this.getText(), textX, textY);

}
```

I do not have any other methods in my button class except the Constructor with super() in it.
The Class inherits from the JButton class and I set the foreground attribute to Color.white in the testing program and added the button via

```
frame.getContentPane().add(button);
```

Because my reputation is not high enough I could not insert the screenshots into the question I am using the imgur links instead.
If I am not allowed to post the links in my question I will delete them immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've broken the paint chain, you MUST call `super.paintComponent`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
```

Essentially, `Graphics` is a shared resource, each component painted will use the same `Graphics` context, meaning that unless you clear it first, you may still have what was previously painted to it still there.  One of the jobs for `paintComponent` is to clear the `Graphics` context with the background color of the component...

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Make sure you are using `setOpaque(false)` to make the component transparent, otherwise you could end up with other issues.  You may also want to use `setBorderPaint`, `setFocusPainted` and `setContentAreaFilled` to change the way that the default look and feel delegates paint the button

Comment: Thanks, this worked with no problems, there is just one thing that bothers me right now, when I click the Button it highlights in the normal JButton colors and I did not find any property to change that color.

Comment: The selection color is probably coming directly from the `UIManager`

Comment: If I set contentAreaFilled(false) then it does not change the color on click, I also added setOpaque(false). But now my Font is rather bold and fuzzy even after I checked it to be plain. I am using Tahoma Plain, 11px

Comment: It's probable that the text is getting painting twice, once by the UI delegate and once by you.  `JButton` is a complex little component it might be better to devices your own UI delegate